# drupal 7 display user info for current user

Tags: users, views

I need to display `name, role, photo` of current user. I'm use `views`, in `Advanced settings` add `Contextual filters` select `Content: Author uid` and in settings of it select Provide default value ,in type selectbox choose `User ID from logged in user`. But in fields i haven't field 'user:name'. If i create relationship content : author , user name will be displayed, but only for users, that published node. At the end, i want see like this

```
Hello, SmithJN
Role: Authorised user
Photo: [photo]
```

Comment: When you create the view, at the very first screen, you have the option to select the entity type on which you want to create the view. Perhaps you want to create a view of type User?

Comment: Wah! i don't see this. try to do.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you create the view, at the very first screen, you have the option to select the entity type on which you want to create the view. (thank J.Reynolds)

Then in Fields add Field `Name, Role, Image`
In Fileter Criteria add filter `User : current`

It's all !